# glyphicon is not working in my bootstrap application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I simply written code for search (input type and search icon), search icon is not displaying .

Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .inner-addon {
   position: relative;
 }

 .inner-addon .glyphicon {
   position: absolute;
   padding: 10px;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .right-addon .glyphicon {
   right: 0px;
 }

 .right-addon input {
   padding-right: 30px;
 }
```

Comment: able to see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/jajwentt/).Check your external files of bootstrap.

Comment: Check your CDN file, might be causing issues.

Comment: didn't know glyphicons work with <i> too, i always use them with <span> as in documentation

Comment: @Hazard, suggest you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you, making sure that you are not missing any css or js in your html. Code should work.

```
<code>https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/cyCFS/</code>
```

Thanks